# Use GDB to examine Objective C class from crash (HandleDelegateSource bad access)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gdb, arm

I am trying to debug an intermittent error on the iPhone, a crash with a trace that looks like:

```
objc_message_send
__invoking__
[NSInvocation invoke]
HandleDelegateSource
MainRunLoop
....
```

When GDB stops, I'd like to be able to determine details about what selector the system is attempting to be invoked - I've set a break point now around [NSInvocation Invoke], but from that point cannot figure out how to examine details of the NSInvocation object I am stopped in.

Comment: [This article](http://www.phrack.org/issues.html?issue=66&id=4#article), recently published at Phrack should answer all your questions. Enlightening reading.

Answer (score 2):

A simple final answer - in GDB you can simply view the register with the name of the selector being called (theSelector parameter in lothar's answer).  It's a C string, so you observe it using one of the following commands (depending on if you are running in the simulator or the device):

```
Simulator: display /s $ecx
Device: display /s $r1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the reference information for [objc_msgSend](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/objc_msgSend) you will see that the selector is the second argument. Now it should be easier to decipher the debugger output.

> objc_msgSend
>   Sends a message with a simple return value to an instance of a class.
>   id objc_msgSend(id theReceiver, SEL theSelector, ...)
>
> Parameters
>   theReceiver
>     A pointer that points to the instance of the class that is to receive the message.
>   theSelector
>     The selector of the method that handles the message.
>   ...
>   A variable argument list containing the arguments to the method.